# Trim numbers from end of SQL variable

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, trim

I have a SQL variable called `@FileName` which I need to trim numbers off the end. Heres an example of how my strings look at the moment, and how i need them to be:

`lorem-1` to `lorem`

`lorem-ipsum-456` to `lorem-ipsum` *(**note**: '-' in the middle remains)*

`foo-123-bar-1234` to `foo-123-bar` *(**note**: number in the middle remains)*

`123-lorem` to `123-lorem` *(**note**: no change as no number and '-' at the end)*

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using `PATINDEX` and `REVERSE`. Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(@FileName,LEN(@FileName)-patindex('%[^0-9]%',REVERSE(@FileName))+1)
```

Comment: cheers for this! However, when I put in 'test-123' for example, it returns 'test-'. Is there anyway of returning just 'test'?

Comment: Ok, for that to work, you need to add all the chars that you want to skip in the PATINDEX. For example, to take away the last number and the preceding "-", you need to add the "-" in the first parameter of the PATINDEX. In this case, it would be this sentence:
SELECT LEFT(@FileName,LEN(@FileName)-patindex('%[^0-9-]%',REVERSE(@FileName))+1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Hava a look at the SUBSTRING & ASCII TSQL functions.

Comment: I'm aware of the SUBSTRING function and have use it many times in the past. However, how would I know what length I want my substring to be?

Comment: One way would be to use substring to look at the characters, one by one, in reverse order. When numbers are encountered, skip them. ASCII could be used to determine if a character is number, with a bit less code than a CASE or IF statement. PATINDEX looks like a better bet though.